# Initialize an empty csv in python?

Tags: python, csv

Is it possible to initialize an empty csv file in python? I want to initialize one and then merge each csv file in a directory into it one by one.

Comment: Suggest you explain what you've already done to figure out the CSV API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just `read()` and `write()` to a file via `open('file' 'a')` for `append`

```
files = ['the', 'files', 'here']
output = '/output/file/here'

for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as input_file:
        with open(output, 'a') as output_file:
            output_file.write(input_file.read())
```

No need to create an empty file first.